# Nested template class invoke the template function

Tags: c++, qt

This is the simplified code of my project.

First i have a template class:

```
template<typename T>
class Base : public QObject{
public:

    void createTemp(){
        qDebug()<<(new T)->metaObject()->className();
    }

    void* mCreateTemp;

    Base(){
        mCreateTemp = (void*)(&Base::createTemp);
    }
};
```

Then two type class `TempA` and `TempB`:

```
class TempA : public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
};

class TempB : public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
};
```

And two class `A` and `B` which derived from `Base`:

```
class A : public Base<TempA>{
    Q_OBJECT
};

class B : public Base<TempB>{
public:
    B(){
        A* a = new A;

        QVariant v = QVariant::fromValue(a);
        //This v is actually passed from QML

        QObject* aa = v.value<QObject*>();
        // I don't want do (A*)a in my project.

        qDebug()<<"Problem wrong answer:";
        ((Base*)(aa))->createTemp();
        qDebug()<<"Soluation:";
        ((void(*)())(((Base*)(aa))->mCreateTemp))();
    }
};
```

The output:

```
Problem wrong answer:
TempB
Soluation:
TempA
```

Simplify the problem:
I am trying to do something like this in `B` class:

```
A* test = new A;
((Base*)test)->createTemp();
```

And I want `TempA` is created.

I already got the solution, store the function as the pointer, but want to know other better way to do this.

Comment: not sure if I understand the problem, but do you maybe want a `virtual createTemp` ?

Comment: `((Base*)(aa))` is in fact `((Base<TempB>*)(aa))` as `Base` is an injected name.

Comment: btw "// I don't want do (A*)a in my project." ... thats good because you should use `dynamic_cast<A*>(a)` instead ;)

Comment: Could you have a common base class ?

Comment: `createTemp()` is a member function, but in `((void(*)())(((Base*)(aa))->mCreateTemp))();` it seems like you call it as a free function. Surely that is not the correct way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using a real base class:

```
class Base : public QObject
{
public:
    virtual void print() const = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class Wrapper : public Base
{
public:
    void print() const override {
        std::cout << typeid(T).name << std::endl;
        // T t;
        // qDebug()<< t.metaObject()->className();
    }
};

class TempA : public QObject{ Q_OBJECT };
class TempB : public QObject{ Q_OBJECT };

class A : public Wrapper<TempA>{ Q_OBJECT };

class B : public Wrapper<TempB>
{
public:
    B(){
        A a;

        QVariant v = QVariant::fromValue(&a); //This v is actually passed from QML

        QObject* aa = v.value<QObject*>();

        auto* base = dynamic_cast<Base*>(aa);
        if (base) {
             base->print();
        }
    }
};
```